# UISearchBar expand into statusbar programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` that moves to just below of statusbar when user enters which should also extend to *fill* statusbar at the same time. I have seen that `UISearchController` does it (expanding to statusbar) with animation. So, **how** can I make `UISearchBar` extend to status bar based on **condition**?

I've tried implementing `UIBarPositioning`, but it seems to be called only once. Is there any way to force `UISearchBar` to call `UIBarPositioning` again?

```
func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {        
    if isUp {
        return .topAttached
    }

    return .top
}
```

Any alternative way would also be appreciated.

#### Details

My searchbar looks like this when it is under statusbar:

[image]

However, it should extend to the statusbar (based on condition) like this:

[image]

`UISearchBarController` does not meet my criteria,  I am implementing `UISearchBarDelegate` myself.

Please, do **not** suggest changing statusbar color.

Comment: Use this `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`

Comment: @zsteed read post carefully, especially last 2 sentences

Comment: I see, sorry I only skimmed it. Is your search bar imbedded in a navigation bar or is it a subview of the UIView?

Comment: @zsteed it is just `subview`, I translate it from center to top and hide the `navigationBar` (all with animation)